# Excel VSTO Addin Using ChromiumFX Issue

Tags: excel, chromium-embedded, excel-addins

I'm trying to invoke browser control in a Window Form using ChromiumFX framework in the Excel VSTO Addin.

The excel application throws the following alerts and another excel instance gets started.

Sorry, we couldn't find Files\Microsoft.xlsx. Is is possible it was removed, renamed of deleted ?
Sorry, we couldn't find Office\root\Office16\debug.log. Is is possible it was removed, renamed of deleted ?
Although I’m able to load the URL in the Web Browser control but i get the above errors multiple time and every time another instance of excel gets initiated.

I’m invoking the following piece of code after which the alerts start appearing.

```
var assemblyDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath);
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(assemblyDir, @".");

if (CfxRuntime.PlatformArch == CfxPlatformArch.x64)
    CfxRuntime.LibCefDirPath = @"cef\Release64";
else
    CfxRuntime.LibCefDirPath = @"cef\Release";

Chromium.WebBrowser.ChromiumWebBrowser.OnBeforeCfxInitialize += ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCfxInitialize;
ChromiumWebBrowser.OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing += ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing;

Chromium.WebBrowser.ChromiumWebBrowser.Initialize();
```

Any suggestions on what i might be doing wrong ? Or what piece of code i’m missing ?

Comment: I have figured out that i have to create and execute a separate renderer process through Settings.BrowserSubprocessPath. Is there any example using ChromiumFx framework which i can refer ?

Comment: I figured out that i have to create and execute a separate assembly for the Browser Renderer Process from the Addin otherwise it will relaunch Excel for the render process again.